# ng-repeat doesn't update its elements on array change

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Why doesn't the following code update `list-group` every second with a new element?

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">ng-repeat with bootstrap list-item</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="list-group">
          <button type="button" class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="item in data">
            {{item}}
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
var app= angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.controller("MyController", function($scope) {
    $scope.data = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];
    window.setInterval(function() {
      console.log("setTimeout");
      $scope.data.push("five");
    }, 1000);
});
```

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` would run `interval` function out of angular context, which will not intimate angular digest cycle system to run digest cycle. Resultant the bindings will not updated.

So for the same angular provided a service called `$interval` which kicks a digest cycle after each specified `interval`(you can event turn digest cycle of). That's why use `$interval` instead of `setInterval`.

```
//inject $interval before using it.
$interval(function() {
  console.log("setTimeout");
  $scope.data.push("five");
}, 1000);
```

Comment: The problem in the real-world application is a bit different. Instead of adding new elements to the array in `setInterval` method I do so in the `WebSocket.onmessage` method. What should I do then to update `list-group` accordingly?

Comment: @FrozenHeart could you please elaborate more on it??

Comment: Instead of doing `$scope.data.push("five");` in the `setInterval` I do the same thing in the `WebSocket.onmessage` method

Comment: @FrozenHeart So I'd suggest you to use `$timeout` for the same, then you can use `setInterval` happily. like `$timeout(function(){$scope.data.push("five");});`, buy using $timeout you will make sure that whenever you update `$scope`, `$timeout` will help you to keep binding in sync by running digest cycle

Comment: Ah, you don't get me right. Ok, I got your answer for the `setInterval`, but it was here for the demonstration purposes only. In the real application I'm trying to add new elements to the array in the `WebSocket.onmessage` method, not in the `setInterval` callback, and I don't get any updates for the `list-group` for some reason

Comment: @FrozenHeart that's what I said, if you explained is the case, then you just only need to make sure that use `$timeout` function wrap around `scope` updation operation, that's it..

Comment: No, you're still talking about `setInterval` and `$interval`stuff. Let me clarify it one more time: I don't have any `interval`-related stuff in my real application, I just used it for the demonstration purposes. However, I'm using `WebSocket.onmessage` method where I'm updating array that should be displayed in the `list-group`, and it doesn't updated (I guess for the same reason as in the case of `setInterval`). Maybe I need smth like `$apply`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136047/discussion-between-pankaj-parkar-and-frozenheart).

Answer (score 0):

One way is to call if you want to use **`setInterval`**

```
 $scope.$apply();
```

With angular you can use **`$interval`**

**DEMO**

```js
var app= angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.controller("MyController", function($scope) {
    $scope.data = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];
    window.setInterval(function() {
      console.log("setTimeout");
      $scope.data.push("five");
      $scope.$apply();
    }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">ng-repeat with bootstrap list-item</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="list-group">
          <button type="button" class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="item in data">
            {{item}}
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem in the real-world application is a bit different. Instead of adding new elements to the array in `setInterval` method I do so in the `WebSocket.onmessage` method. What should I do then to update `list-group` accordingly?